# Select statement which joins to a another table with where definitions inside

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table which contains the where selection. For example `ExpressionTable`:

```
ID      WhereCase
------------------
1       = 4 
2       in(2,3)
3       = 3
4       in(4,5,6)
```

Now I need to select from another table with this WhereCase.

```
Select * from tablexy join ExpressionTable as et on tablexy.ID = et.ID
Where Country (this (WhereCase) from the ExpressionTable)
```

When I write `where Country = et.WhereCase` is not working...

What is the best way for this?

Comment: What is not working? Does it throw an error or the query doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way for this...

Don't do it.

Based on the example expressions you have provided you can easily store this information in a relational format that can then be joined onto (or appended onto the query with an `EXISTS` clause to keep the same semantics with respect to Duplicates).

```
CREATE TABLE XyCountries
  (
     XyID    INT,
     Country INT
  );

INSERT INTO XyCountries
VALUES      (1,4),
            (2,2),
            (2,3),
            (3,3),
            (4,4),
            (4,5),
            (4,6);
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Don't know why someone downvoted it.

Comment: @Tobsey - Fairly sure it was an unrelated revenge downvote for a comment I left on a nonsensical answer [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17165891/73226) as another old question of mine was downvoted at the same time and the answer was also deleted at that time.

Answer (score 0):

you cant have dynamic query conditions.
The only way to achieve what you want is to use dynamic SQL where you build your query in a string and them execute it like EXEC ('select 1')

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build a SQL statement using Dynamic SQL and then execute it, eg

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = 'Select * from tablexy Where Country ' + et.WhereCase FROM ExpressionTable WHERE ID = ?
```

Then execute:

```
EXEC(@SQL)
```