# Stored procedure taking more than query

Tags: sql-server

Stored procedure is taking 5 minutes to execute, but if query of which I have written procedure then it will take on 4 sec. I did google and find parameters sniffing for improving procedures performance so implemented that and now it still taking 3 minutes.

What should I do?

Thanks

Atul yadav

Here is my stored procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_all]
    @para_factor_id int, 
    @para_factor_client_id int, 
    @para_factor_customer_id int, 
    @para_invoice_date_from date, 
    @para_invoice_date_to date, 
    @para_invoice_amount_from decimal(18, 2), 
    @para_invoice_amount_to decimal(18, 2), 
    @para_invoice_id int, 
    @para_schedule_number varchar(400), 
    @para_invoice_number varchar(400), 
    @para_schedule_id int, 
    @para_invoice_status_id varchar(50), 
    @para_marked_for_printing bit, 
    @para_user_id int, 
    @para_role_id int, 
    @para_current_date date, 
    @para_approval_status_id int = 0, 
    @para_is_verified int = 0, 
    @para_load_number varchar(400) = ''
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @var_invoice_order   INT
             = (SELECT invoice_order
                  FROM factor_default_settings fds
                 WHERE fds.factor_id = @para_factor_id);

    DECLARE @v_factor_id   INT;
    DECLARE @v_factor_client_id   INT;
    DECLARE @v_factor_customer_id   INT;
    DECLARE @v_invoice_date_from   DATETIME;
    DECLARE @v_invoice_date_to   DATETIME;
    DECLARE @v_invoice_amount_from   DECIMAL (18, 2);
    DECLARE @v_invoice_amount_to   DECIMAL (18, 2);
    DECLARE @v_invoice_id   INT;
    DECLARE @v_schedule_number   VARCHAR (400);
    DECLARE @v_invoice_number   VARCHAR (400);
    DECLARE @v_schedule_id   INT;
    DECLARE @v_invoice_status_id   VARCHAR (50);
    DECLARE @v_marked_for_printing   BIT;
    DECLARE @v_user_id   INT;
    DECLARE @v_role_id   INT;
    DECLARE @v_current_date   DATETIME;
    DECLARE @v_approval_status_id   INT;
    DECLARE @v_is_verified   INT;
    DECLARE @v_load_number   VARCHAR (400);

    SET @v_factor_id = @para_factor_id;
    SET @v_factor_client_id = @para_factor_client_id;
    SET @v_factor_customer_id = @para_factor_customer_id;
    SET @v_invoice_date_from = @para_invoice_date_from;
    SET @v_invoice_date_to = @para_invoice_date_to;
    SET @v_invoice_amount_from = @para_invoice_amount_from;
    SET @v_invoice_amount_to = @para_invoice_amount_to;
    SET @v_invoice_id = @para_invoice_id;
    SET @v_schedule_number = @para_schedule_number;
    SET @v_invoice_number = @para_invoice_number;
    SET @v_schedule_id = @para_schedule_id;
    SET @v_invoice_status_id = @para_invoice_status_id;
    SET @v_marked_for_printing = @para_marked_for_printing;
    SET @v_user_id = @para_user_id;
    SET @v_role_id = @para_role_id;
    SET @v_current_date = @para_current_date;
    SET @v_approval_status_id = @para_approval_status_id;
    SET @v_is_verified = @para_is_verified;
    SET @v_load_number = @para_load_number;

    SET  NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 300
         inv.factor_id,
         inv.invoice_id,
         inv.schedule_id,
         inv.term_id,
         inv.factor_client_id,
         inv.factor_customer_id,
         inv_trn.client_name,
         SUBSTRING (inv_trn.client_name, 1, 10) AS client_name_10,
         inv_trn.customer_name,
         SUBSTRING (inv_trn.customer_name, 1, 10) AS customer_name_10,
         sch.schedule_number,
         sch.payment_method_id,
         inv.invoice_number,
         inv.po_number,
         inv.invoice_date,
         inv.est_days_out,
         (CASE
             WHEN inv.manually_flagged = 1
             THEN
                1
             ELSE
                CASE
                   WHEN     inv.flag_days > 0
                        AND inv.discount_calculation_date >
                               CONVERT (DATE, '1900/01/01')
                   THEN
                      CASE
                         WHEN DATEDIFF (DAY,
                                        inv.discount_calculation_date,
                                        @v_current_date) > inv.flag_days
                         THEN
                            1
                         ELSE
                            0
                      END
                   ELSE
                      0
                END
          END)
            AS flag_days_icon,
         inv.flag_days,
         inv.float_days,
         DATEADD (DAY, inv.est_days_out, inv.invoice_date) AS due_date,
         inv.invoice_amount,
         inv.credit_limit_exceeded_by_client,
         inv.po_duplication_status,
         inv.advance_amount,
         inv.advance_calculation_decision_id,
         inv.advance_percent,
         inv.advance_calculation_formula,
         (CASE inv.deduct_discount_from_advance
             WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes'
             ELSE 'No'
          END)
            AS deduct_discount_from_advance,
         deduct_discount_from_advance AS deduct_discount,
         inv.verified,
         inv.estimated_advance_date,
         inv_trn.notes_count,
         inv.net_term,
         inv_trn.total_adjustment_amount,
         inv.approval_status_id,
         inv_apr_stat.approval_status,
         sch.submitted,
         sch.made_by_client,
         sch.submitted_by_client,
         sch.authorized_by_client,
         inv.invoice_status_id,
         inv_st.invoice_status,
         inv.verified,
         inv.client_customer_id,
         CAST (inv_trn.attachment_count AS INT) AS attachment_count,
         ROUND ( (inv.advance_amount - inv_trn.advance_discount), 2)
            AS payment_amount,
         (inv_trn.escrow_advance - pmt.total_escrow_amount)
            AS escrow_amount,
         inv_trn.dilution_type_id,
         inv_trn.dilution,
         inv_trn.dilution_amount,
         inv_trn.dilution_term_rate_id,
         inv_trn.po_deduction_type_id,
         inv.po_id,
         inv.fuel_advance,
         inv.fuel_adv_with_adj,
         inv.dispute
    FROM invoices inv
         JOIN dbo.fun_get_client_list_profile_management (@v_factor_id,
                                                          @v_user_id,
                                                          @v_role_id,
                                                          1) fun_cl
            ON inv.factor_client_id = fun_cl.factor_client_id
         JOIN factor_customers fact_cust
            ON     inv.factor_customer_id = fact_cust.factor_customer_id
               AND (   inv.factor_customer_id = @v_factor_customer_id
                    OR @v_factor_customer_id = 0)
         JOIN factor_clients fact_cl
            ON inv.factor_client_id = fact_cl.factor_client_id
         JOIN client_customers cl_cust
            ON inv.client_customer_id = cl_cust.client_customer_id
         JOIN invoice_transaction_values inv_trn
            ON inv.invoice_id = inv_trn.invoice_id
         JOIN schedules sch
            ON inv.schedule_id = sch.schedule_id
         JOIN invoice_total_payments pmt
            ON     inv.invoice_id = pmt.invoice_id
               AND pmt.payment_type_id = 1
         JOIN invoice_approval_status inv_apr_stat
            ON inv.approval_status_id = inv_apr_stat.approval_status_id
         JOIN invoice_status inv_st
            ON inv.invoice_status_id = inv_st.invoice_status_id
         LEFT JOIN (SELECT inv_prop.invoice_id,
                           inv_prop.mark_for_printing
                      FROM invoice_properties inv_prop
                           JOIN invoices inv
                              ON inv_prop.invoice_id = inv.invoice_id
                           JOIN factor_clients fact_cl
                              ON inv.factor_client_id =
                                    fact_cl.factor_client_id
                           JOIN factor_customers fact_cust
                              ON inv.factor_customer_id =
                                    fact_cust.factor_customer_id
                     WHERE     inv.factor_id = @v_factor_id
                           AND (   inv.factor_client_id =
                                      @v_factor_client_id
                                OR @v_factor_client_id = 0)
                           AND (   inv.factor_customer_id =
                                      @v_factor_customer_id
                                OR @v_factor_customer_id = 0)
                           AND fact_cl.active = 1
                           AND fact_cust.active = 1) AS inv_prop
            ON inv_prop.invoice_id = inv.invoice_id
         LEFT JOIN invoice_custom_field_values inv_cust_fld_val
            ON     inv.invoice_id = inv_cust_fld_val.invoice_id
               AND inv_cust_fld_val.custom_field_id = 4
    WHERE     inv.factor_id = @v_factor_id
         AND (   inv.factor_client_id = @v_factor_client_id
              OR @v_factor_client_id = 0)
         AND (   inv.factor_customer_id = @v_factor_customer_id
              OR @v_factor_customer_id = 0)
         AND fact_cl.active = 1
         AND fact_cust.active = 1
         AND cl_cust.active = 1
         AND inv.invoice_amount BETWEEN @v_invoice_amount_from
                                    AND @v_invoice_amount_to
         AND inv.invoice_date BETWEEN @v_invoice_date_from
                                  AND @v_invoice_date_to
         AND (inv.invoice_id = @v_invoice_id OR @v_invoice_id = 0)
         AND (inv.schedule_id = @v_schedule_id OR @v_schedule_id = 0)
         AND sch.schedule_number LIKE '%' + @v_schedule_number + '%'
         AND inv.invoice_number LIKE '%' + @v_invoice_number + '%'
         AND (   inv.invoice_status_id IN
                    (SELECT items
                       FROM dbo.fun_split_string (@v_invoice_status_id,
                                                  ','))
              OR @v_invoice_status_id = '')
         --             AND (   ISNULL (inv_prop.mark_for_printing,
         --                             @v_marked_for_printing) = 0
         --                  OR @v_marked_for_printing = 0)
         AND (   ISNULL (inv_prop.mark_for_printing, 0) =
                    @v_marked_for_printing
              OR @v_marked_for_printing = 0)
         AND (   (    @v_role_id IN (2, 6)
                  AND (   sch.submitted_by_client = 1
                       OR sch.made_by_client = 0))
              OR (@v_role_id IN (3, 10)))
         AND (   inv.approval_status_id = @v_approval_status_id
              OR @v_approval_status_id = 0)
         AND (@v_is_verified = 0 OR inv.verified = 1)
         AND (   (inv_cust_fld_val.value LIKE '%' + @v_load_number + '%')
              OR @v_load_number = '')
         AND inv.approval_status_id IN (1,2)
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN @var_invoice_order = 1 THEN inv.invoice_date END ASC,
           CASE WHEN @var_invoice_order = 1 THEN inv.invoice_id END ASC,
           CASE WHEN @var_invoice_order = 2 THEN inv.invoice_date END DESC,
           CASE WHEN @var_invoice_order = 2 THEN inv.invoice_id END DESC
END
```

Comment: Showing some of the code might help people answering it

Comment: What fix did you use for parameter sniffing? Assigning to variables? If so try `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. If still the same issue maybe your parameters are of the wrong type causing an implicit cast and less efficient plan.

Comment: I supose your proc contains more than one join. Sql does his own ejoin order which is may differ from yours. I think is OPTION FORCE ORDER.

Comment: I added my procedure code....

Comment: @zespri Hmm.. `some` code has been added :))

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to change in the stored proc first.

1) implement indexes (if not there).

2) Do not use function in join "dbo.fun_get_client_list_profile_management"
Instead of that you need to create a temp table/table variable and populate that with dbo.fun_get_client_list_profile_management and then join the temp table/table variable with the actual query. Because when you use function instead of table the function is called for each row results.

3) Same thing you need to do for "inv_prop". Populate a temp table/ table variable with that subquery and then use that table in actual query.

4) Same thing goes for

```
inv.invoice_status_id IN
                (SELECT items
                   FROM dbo.fun_split_string (@v_invoice_status_id,
                                              ','))
          OR @v_invoice_status_id = ''
```

Change it to table variables and instead of "IN" use join

Change those things and let us know the improvement.

Comment: Most of what you've suggested shouldn't explain why the proc is slower than the query. They're all general performance tuning. Not sure where you got # 3 from without seeing an execution plan...Agree with #2 & 4 but not for your reasonings. TVFs are notorious for contributing to bad plans when they return large result sets because they don't have statistics (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109152/table-valued-function-killing-my-query-performance). Same goes for table variables.

Comment: @Atul Can you give your latest stored proc ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have a bad plan in the cache for that stored procedure. Recompile it and see if the performance is comparable to the query.

```
EXEC sp_recompile N'dbo.get_all';
```